# US citizen born in Mexico

Tags: visas, usa, mexico

I am a US citizen born in Mexico. I am traveling to Mexico in a couple of weeks with my American passport. Do I need a visa or anything else to travel?

Comment: -1 for not undertaking a basic research online before asking this question.

Comment: do you have any Mexican document?

Comment: What are you doing in Mexico? Working? Studying? Vacation?

Comment: If you were born in Mexico, you're most probably a [citizen of Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_nationality_law) unless you've renounced your Mexican citizenship.

Comment: @SheikPaul Probably not a duplicate of that, given that the asker has Mexican nationality by being born there.

Comment: @DavidRicherby As I understand it, Mexico used to have a more active stance against dual citizenship, Although that may not have prohibited people from having both nationalities by birth, it's worth considering the possibility that a US citizen born in Mexico might not possess both citizenships.

Comment: @SheikPaul according to the Wikipedia article, Mexico has birthright citizenship and requires its citizens to travel to the US with documents showing Mexican citizenship.  If Wikipedia is correct, then this question is not a duplicate of the other one, as the answer to this question depends on determining whether yenny is a Mexican citizen.  I have voted to reopen.

Comment: @phoog Note that Mexico differentiates between nationality and citizenship. In any case, we're agreed that this question isn't a dupe. It probably can't be answered without knowing the asker's status in Mexico.

Comment: @SheikPaul questions that show little research effort should be downvoted rather than closed ("lack of effort" is not a close reason, after all).

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted, those born in Mexican territory are citizens of Mexico, regardless of the nationality of their parents.

The [Mexican nationality law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_nationality_law) acknowledges that a Mexican by birth may possess another nationality. If that is the case, however, such an individual must always enter and leave the country as a Mexican (by presenting a Mexican proof of citizenship).

Mexico actively encourages dual citizenship (Doble Nacionalidad) and US/Mexican nationals should carry citizenship documentation for both countries when traveling to Mexico.

[Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=PA&COUNTRY=mx&SUBSECTION=PT&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines, lists the what Mexican documents are acceptable if you don't have a Mexican passport:

- national ID card
- certified copy of birth certificate
- consular registration
- certificate of Mexican nationality
- naturalization letter
- Matricula Consular
- Constancia de Identificacion
- voter's certificate with photo